# How to create new index pattern with custom pattern ID from the elastic API?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, kibana

I created new index with the ES Node.js API and inserted some documents into it.
Now I want to create an index pattern automatically when the index is first created

Answer (score 1):

To create mapping to specific indices while created you need to set `template` with `index_patterns` parameter.

```
PUT _template/fruits
{
  "index_patterns": ["banana*", "apple*"],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 2
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "time_of_my_life": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when you create index `banana1` or `apple_7` it will have predefined mapping you’ve created in your template.

```
PUT banana1
GET banana1/_mapping

{
  "banana1" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "_source" : {
        "enabled" : false
      },
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "time_of_my_life" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually what I want to achieve is to create an index pattern on Kibana UI without doing it manually. Tnx anyway